# What sounds could a (~15ft humanoid) Giant make?

Tags: vocalizations, giant

The first question of what will likely be a kind of "mini series" of giant-related questions I have!

TL;DR - creating a giant race. Average height is approximately 15ft, they are intelligent and humanoid. (More *giant elves* than *giant humans* in appearance.)

**I'd love to hear feedback/ideas/discussions/etc. on the plausible sounds & noises such a creature could make.** *(Beyond basic speech.)* Hisses, snarls, growls, rumbles, etc. How they could make them, why they could make them, what they would sound like, etc. It would really help me out in developing my own race. Big thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: (After the automatic message ^^) Hi and welcome, just so you know this site is better dealing with specific problems than sharing general feedbacks or starting discussion -it's hard to take out the best ideas-. For your next questions, I'd advise to focus on a specific issue you're having when making your giants, it'll avoid them from getting closed for this reason :). You can get more info on what is commonly accepted or not in the [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help-center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if you wish!

Comment: For the other question I linked, can you tell why the answers there aren't helping you? I see a formula which could be applied to know the frequency any giant would roughly have if scientifically accurate, perhaps it's a good start? If you find nothing of value for you there, please tell us why so we can take your question under a new light .

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for the welcome! I'll be sure to check out the tour & help-center linked! As for your first link, it doesn't really help me due to the fact that question centers around 50-foot-tall giants. Since my own are not as huge, I can't gleam much from the answers. It's likewise asking a different question - the basic "what would they sound like," whereas I am asking, "what sounds COULD they make." (i.e. could they perhaps "rumble" in the same way elephants do, could they hiss like alligators, etc.)

Comment: @EmpressFreyja What sounds "could" they make depends on your worldbuilding intentions ^^. The linked question asked under the light of "realism" (including a formula which can be used for 15ft giants), this is one of possible intentions. But if you wish to they can just sound a little bit heavier to stress their weight while still being human voiceable/understandable... Or be 3 octaves higher for a comedy effect. In short, it's something I think is best chosen by yourself, as only you are in the best position to know what you want to tell in your world :).

Comment: I'm glad you're planning a series of questions! Please note two things: first is that SE isn't a discussion forum, it's a Q&A. So this isn't the place to look for feedback and discussion. Second is that anywhere you go on SE, you get to ask one question per query. You're asking at least four here! Please edit your question so that you're focusing on one question only!